# Jbehave print the steps twice

Tags: logging, logback, slf4j, jbehave

I ran our Jbehave tests in IntelliJ, it print to console, one thing I noticed is each story step it print twice, example:

```
2019-05-30 08:11:09 [pool-19-thread-1] INFO  c.s.c.cassandra.CassandraRepository - Looking in the table member_by_account_id
Then poll MemberByAccountId table for view processor
Then poll MemberByAccountId table for view processor
And verify the MemberByAccountId payload in view table
And verify the MemberByAccountId payload in view table
Given modify ingestion payload to appear older
Given modify ingestion payload to appear older
2019-05-30 08:11:09 [pool-19-thread-1] DEBUG c.s.c.j.m.s.VerifyServiceSteps - published message [{"topic":"/subscriptions","subject":"Message","id":"xxxxx",...}"}}] published date 2019-04-30T15:11:09.584Z 
When publish the payload to ingestion eventHub
When publish the payload to ingestion eventHub
2019-05-30 08:11:09 [pool-19-thread-1] DEBUG c.s.c.j.m.s.VerifyServiceSteps - looking for date 2019-04-30
2019-05-30 08:11:09 [pool-19-thread-1] INFO  c.s.c.cassandra.CassandraRepository - Looking in the table ingest_audit
```

all the entries with INFO/DEBUG are from java code from org.slf4j.Logger, other entries from printed from Jbehave, and you can tell each step it print twice. there is only one thread (pool-19-thread-1) besides the main thread.

here is the configuration for story runner:

```java
public AbstractJbehaveStoryRunner() {
    List<String> filters =
        Arrays.stream(System.getProperty("meta.filter", "").split(","))
            .map(String::trim)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    LOGGER.debug("filters------" + filters);

    embedder.useMetaFilters(filters);
    embedder.useTimeoutParsers(timeout);
    this.useEmbedder(embedder);
    initJBehaveConfiguration();
  }

  protected String[] getStepConfigResources() {
    return new String[0];
  }

  private void initJBehaveConfiguration() {
    Class<?> thisClass = this.getClass();

    ExamplesTableFactory examplesTableFactory =
        new ExamplesTableFactory(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass()), new TableTransformers());

    useConfiguration(
        new MostUsefulConfiguration()
            .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(thisClass.getClassLoader()))
            .usePendingStepStrategy(new FailingUponPendingStep())
            .useStepdocReporter(new PrintStreamStepdocReporter())
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(
                new StoryReporterBuilder()
                    .withReporters(new ConsoleOutput())
                    .withFailureTrace(true)
                    .withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(thisClass))
                    .withDefaultFormats()
                    .withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.TXT, Format.HTML, Format.XML, Format.STATS)
                    .withCrossReference(new CrossReference()))
            .useParameterConverters(
                new ParameterConverters()
                    .addConverters(
                        new ParameterConverters.DateConverter(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"))))
            .useStoryParser(new RegexStoryParser(examplesTableFactory))
            .useStepMonitor(new SilentStepMonitor()));
  }
```

and here is the logback config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <property name="DEV_HOME" value="/root/var/log"/>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
      </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
      </fileNamePattern>
      <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
    </rollingPolicy>

  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE-ERROR"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/error.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
      </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
      </fileNamePattern>
      <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
    </rollingPolicy>

  </appender>

  <!-- Send logs to both console and file audit -->
  <logger name="com.starbucks.comptest" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </logger>

  <root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR"/>
  </root>

</configuration>
```

how can i remove that duplicated step print?

Comment: Could you please provide your logger configuration?

Comment: @VaL: added logger configuration in the post.